# Is there a positive element on the dual of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, duality-theorems

Let $ X $ be a Banach space (complex or real). Is this possible  $$ \sup_{\Vert x^{∗}\Vert \leq 1} x^{∗}(x) ≥0  \quad \forall x\in X.$$
in some Banach spaces, particularly in the Lebesgue space $ X=L^p (R) $ ?

Comment: $x^* = 0$ would be the only one, because if there is a $x$ s.t. $x^*(x) > 0$, then $x^*(-x) = -x^*(x) < 0$

Comment: If there is enough choice yes. It is an immediate consequence of the Hahn Banach theorem and I think it might also be equivalent to the Hahn Banach theorem

Comment: Thanks, now I've changed the question to what interests me

Comment: The supremum is $\ge 0$ for all $x\in X$ if and only if $X=\{0\}$. If there is $x\ne0$ there is $x^*$ such that $x^*(x)<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed formulation, YES.  I consider a real Banach space $X$.  [Taking a supremum of a set of complex numbers is not defined.]

By Hahn-Banach, for a given $x \in X$, we have
$$
\|x\| = \sup\left\{x^*(x)\;:\; x^* \in X^*, \|x^*\| \le 1\right\} .
\tag1$$
The proof may depend on your formulation of Hahn-Banach.  Perhaps you get get only
$$
\|x\| = \sup\left\{|x^*(x)|\;:\; x^* \in X^*, \|x^*\| \le 1\right\};
\tag2$$
but then, since we use real scalars, for each $x^*$ we have
$|x^*(x)| = y^*(x)$ either for $y^*=x^*$ or for $y^* = -x^*$.  So we deduce $(1)$ from $(2)$.

---

For concrete spaces like $L^p$, this can be done explicitly, not requiring Hahn-Banach.
So, let $f \in L^p(\mathbb R)$, $1<p<\infty$, with $\|f\|_p > 0$.  Take
$$
g(x) = \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(f(x))}{\|f\|_p^{p-1}}\;|f(x)|^{p-1}
$$
then show $g \in L^{q}(\mathbb R)$ where $q=(p-1)/p$ and $\|g\|_q = 1$ and
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} fg = \|f\|_p .
$$

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question. Honestly, the question does not make much sense. Maybe there were some now deleted comments?